# Reactive Form with Form Builder

Tags: angular

Getting error 'ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined', i am not understanding why as i have defined in both html and js.

My Html

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>
  <div formArrayName="Quest">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="flag">Quest1</label>
     <input type="radio" class="form-control" value="Y" id="username" name="flag" formControlName = "flag">
     <label for="flag">LastName</label>
     <input type="radio" class="form-control" value="N" id="username" name="flag" formControlName = "flag">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" *ngIf="formName.value.Quest1.flag == 'Y'" id="testName" name="testName" formControlName = "testName">
   </div>
 </div>
</form>     
<button (click)="consoleF(formName.value)">Click</button>                 
<p> value: {{ formName.value | json}}</p>
<p> valid: {{ formName.valid }}</p>`
```

JS

```
  formName = this.fb.group({
    Quest:  this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        QUESTION_ID: this.fb.control('51'),
        flag: this.fb.control(''),
        testName: this.fb.control('')
    })
  ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

[**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-with-form-builder?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>


  <div formArrayName="Quest"
  *ngFor="let item of formName.get('Quest').controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="flag">Quest1</label>
          <input type="radio" class="form-control" value="Y" id="username" name="flag" formControlName = "flag">

          <label for="flag">LastName</label>
          <input type="radio" class="form-control" value="N" id="username" name="flag" formControlName = "flag">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" *ngIf="item.get('flag').value == 'Y'" id="testName" name="testName" formControlName = "testName">
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because flag is defined in Form Array. You have to iterate over each Form Array controls.

Try this:

Component

```
formName = this.fb.group({
  Quest:  this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      QUESTION_ID: this.fb.control('51'),
      flag: this.fb.control(''),
      testName: this.fb.control('')
    })
  ])

get quests() {
    return this.formName.get('Quest') as FormArray;
}
```

HTML File

```
<div *ngFor="let quest of quests.controls; let i = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
        // similarly you can add other fiels from array
        <input type="radio" class="form-control" value="Y" id="username" name="flag" formControlName = "flag">
    </div>
</div>
```

For more details look at [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods

In your .ts, return the form object

```
get f() {
   return this.formName.controls;
}
```

I think, the error arisen in html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" *ngIf="f.Quest.flag == 'Y'" id="testName" name="testName" formControlName = "testName">
```